# How to do Xavier initialization on TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm porting my Caffe network over to TensorFlow but it doesn't seem to have xavier initialization. I'm using `truncated_normal` but this seems to be making it a lot harder to train.

Comment: Xavier is the default initialization. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350131/what-is-the-default-variable-initializer-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In **Tensorflow 2.0** and further both `tf.contrib.*` and `tf.get_variable()` are deprecated. In order to do Xavier initialization you now have to switch to:

```
init = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()
var = tf.Variable(init(shape=shape))
# or a oneliner with a little confusing brackets
var = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()(shape=shape))
```

Glorot uniform and Xavier uniform are two different names of the same initialization type. If you want to know more about how to use initializations in TF2.0 with or without Keras refer to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/GlorotUniform).

Comment: I used the above code and get an error like below;

_init_xavier = tf.Variable(init(shape=shape))
NameError: name 'shape' is not defined

Answer (score 120):

Since version 0.8 there is a Xavier initializer, [see here for the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#xavier_initializer).

You can use something like this:

```
W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[784, 256],
           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Comment: do you know to do this without giving the shape to `get_variable` but instead giving it to the initializer? I used to have `tf.truncated_normal(shape=[dims[l-1],dims[l]], mean=mu[l], stddev=std[l], dtype=tf.float64)` and I specified the shape there but that now your suggestion sort of screws my code up. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Pinocchio you can simply write yourself a wrapper which has the same signature as `tf.Variable(...)` and uses `tf.get_variable(...)`

Comment: "Current" link without version: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer

Answer (score 28):

Just to add another example on how to define a `tf.Variable` initialized using [Xavier and Yoshua](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf)'s method:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    ...
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
    w1 = tf.Variable(initializer(w1_shape))
    b1 = tf.Variable(initializer(b1_shape))
    ...
```

This prevented me from having `nan` values on my loss function due to numerical instabilities when using multiple layers with RELUs.

Comment: This format fitted my code best - and it's allowed me to return my learning rate to 0.5 (I had to lower it to 0.06 when adding another relu'd layer). Once I'd applied this initialiser to ALL hidden layers I'm getting incredibly high validation rates right from the first few hundred epochs. I can't believe the difference it's made!

Answer (score 12):

@Aleph7, Xavier/Glorot initialization depends the number of incoming connections (fan_in), number outgoing connections (fan_out), and kind of activation function (sigmoid or tanh) of the neuron. See this: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

So now, to your question. This is how I would do it in TensorFlow:

```
(fan_in, fan_out) = ...
    low = -4*np.sqrt(6.0/(fan_in + fan_out)) # use 4 for sigmoid, 1 for tanh activation 
    high = 4*np.sqrt(6.0/(fan_in + fan_out))
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, minval=low, maxval=high, dtype=tf.float32))
```

Note that we should be sampling from a uniform distribution, and not the normal distribution as suggested in the other answer.

Incidentally, I wrote a [post yesterday](http://deliprao.com/archives/100) for something different using TensorFlow that happens to also use Xavier initialization. If you're interested, there's also a python notebook with an end-to-end example: https://github.com/delip/blog-stuff/blob/master/tensorflow_ufp.ipynb

Comment: How can we use it with relu activation function.

Comment: That paper studies the behavior of weight gradients under different activation functions with the commonly used initialization. Then they propose a universal initialization regardless of any activation function.

Furthermore, your method also does not depend on activation function either, so it's better to use the built-in Xavier initialization in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 8):

A nice wrapper around `tensorflow` called [`prettytensor`](https://github.com/google/prettytensor) gives an implementation in the source code (copied directly from [here](https://github.com/google/prettytensor/blob/a69f13998258165d6682a47a931108d974bab05e/prettytensor/layers.py)):

```
def xavier_init(n_inputs, n_outputs, uniform=True):
  """Set the parameter initialization using the method described.
  This method is designed to keep the scale of the gradients roughly the same
  in all layers.
  Xavier Glorot and Yoshua Bengio (2010):
           Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural
           networks. International conference on artificial intelligence and
           statistics.
  Args:
    n_inputs: The number of input nodes into each output.
    n_outputs: The number of output nodes for each input.
    uniform: If true use a uniform distribution, otherwise use a normal.
  Returns:
    An initializer.
  """
  if uniform:
    # 6 was used in the paper.
    init_range = math.sqrt(6.0 / (n_inputs + n_outputs))
    return tf.random_uniform_initializer(-init_range, init_range)
  else:
    # 3 gives us approximately the same limits as above since this repicks
    # values greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean.
    stddev = math.sqrt(3.0 / (n_inputs + n_outputs))
    return tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev)
```

Answer (score 8):

TF-contrib has [`xavier_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/initializers#xavier_initializer). Here is an example how to use it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.get_variable("a", shape=[4, 4], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(a)
```

In addition to this, tensorflow has other initializers:

- [xavier_initializer_conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/initializers#xavier_initializer_conv2d)
- [variance_scaling_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/initializers#variance_scaling_initializer)
- [constant_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer)
- [zeros_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_initializer)
- [ones_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_initializer)
- [uniform_unit_scaling_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/uniform_unit_scaling_initializer)
- [truncated_normal_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal_initializer)
- [random_uniform_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform_initializer)
- [random_normal_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal_initializer)
- [orthogonal_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/orthogonal_initializer)
- [as well as a lot of initializers from keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/initializers/he_uniform)

Comment: thanks, sir this was very helpful, I want to ask you if I can initialize the **bias** using  **xavier_initializer**

Answer (score 4):

I looked and I couldn't find anything built in. However, according to this:

http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization

Xavier initialization is just sampling a (usually Gaussian) distribution where the variance is a function of the number of neurons.  `tf.random_normal` can do that for you, you just need to compute the stddev (i.e. the number of neurons being represented by the weight matrix you're trying to initialize).

Comment: Vince you should be sampling from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Via the `kernel_initializer` parameter to `tf.layers.conv2d, tf.layers.conv2d_transpose, tf.layers.Dense`  etc

e.g.

```
layer = tf.layers.conv2d(
     input, 128, 5, strides=2,padding='SAME',
     kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d_transpose

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you want to use one line as you do with:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((n_prev, n), stddev=0.1))
```

You can do:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()((n_prev, n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [25, 12288],
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1)
```

Tensorflow 2:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [25, 12288],
    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=1))
```