# Adding multiple layers to TensorFlow causes loss function to become Nan

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm writing a neural-network classifier in TensorFlow/Python for the [notMNIST](http://yaroslavvb.blogspot.kr/2011/09/notmnist-dataset.html) dataset.  I've implemented l2 regularization and dropout on the hidden layers.  It works fine as long as there is only one hidden layer, but when I added more layers (to improve accuracy), the loss function increases rapidly at each step, becoming NaN by step 5.  I tried temporarily disabling Dropout and L2 regularization, but I get the same behavior as long as there are 2+ layers.  I even rewrote my code from scratch (doing some refactoring to make it more flexible), but with the same results.  The number and size of layers is controlled by `hidden_layer_spec`.  What am I missing?

```
#works for np.array([1024]) with about 96.1% accuracy
hidden_layer_spec = np.array([1024, 300])
num_hidden_layers = hidden_layer_spec.shape[0]
batch_size = 256
beta = 0.0005

epochs = 100
stepsPerEpoch = float(train_dataset.shape[0]) / batch_size
num_steps = int(math.ceil(float(epochs) * stepsPerEpoch))

l2Graph = tf.Graph()
with l2Graph.as_default():
  #with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
      # at run time with a training minibatch.
      tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
      tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
      tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
      tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

      weights = []
      biases = []
      for hi in range(0, num_hidden_layers + 1):
        width = image_size * image_size if hi == 0 else hidden_layer_spec[hi - 1]
        height = num_labels if hi == num_hidden_layers else hidden_layer_spec[hi]
        weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([width, height]), name = "w" + `hi + 1`))
        biases.append(tf.Variable(tf.zeros([height]), name = "b" + `hi + 1`))
        print(`width` + 'x' + `height`)

      def logits(input, addDropoutLayer = False):
        previous_layer = input
        for hi in range(0, hidden_layer_spec.shape[0]):
          previous_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(previous_layer, weights[hi]) + biases[hi])
          if addDropoutLayer:
            previous_layer = tf.nn.dropout(previous_layer, 0.5)
        return tf.matmul(previous_layer, weights[num_hidden_layers]) + biases[num_hidden_layers]

      # Training computation.
      train_logits = logits(tf_train_dataset, True)

      l2 = tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[0])
      for hi in range(1, len(weights)):
        l2 = l2 + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights[0])
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(train_logits, tf_train_labels)) + beta * l2

      # Optimizer.
      global_step = tf.Variable(0)  # count the number of steps taken.
      learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.5, global_step, int(stepsPerEpoch) * 2, 0.96, staircase = True)
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

      # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
      train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(train_logits)
      valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits(tf_valid_dataset))
      test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits(tf_test_dataset))
      saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=l2Graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 500 == 0):
      print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
      print("Learning rate: " % learning_rate)
      print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(
        valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
  print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
  save_path = saver.save(session, "l2_degrade.ckpt")
  print("Model save to " + `save_path`)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out this was not so much a coding issue as a Deep Learning Issue.  The extra layer made the gradients too unstable, and that lead to the loss function quickly devolving to NaN.  The best way to fix this is to use [Xavier initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640581/how-to-do-xavier-initialization-on-tensorflow).  Otherwise, the variance of the initial values will tend to be too high, causing instability.  Also, decreasing the learning rate may help.

Comment: I realize this was a while ago, but you might also want to look into some regularization methods, and specifically into [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf). If you have it working then great, but BN helps with network sensitivity to initial weight distributions, among other things.

Comment: For `truncated_normal`, try setting `stddev=sqrt(2/N)`, where `N` is the number of rows in the weight matrix. Or just set `stddev` to a [lower value](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/problem-3-3-dropout-does-not-improve-test-accuarcy/46286/13). Here's an [example](http://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning/deep-learning/tensorflow/regularization/), though there are some mistakes, such as including dropout in the evaluation step.

Comment: Actually, here's original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852v1.pdf) that the `sqrt(2/N)` comes from.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and reducing the batch size and learning rate worked for me.

Comment: Yes. My learning rate was at a fixed 0.5 and I had to lower it to 0.06 to get it going.