# What is the default variable initializer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

What is the default method of variable initialization used when `tf.get_variable()` is called without any specification for the initializer? The Docs just says 'None'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable):

> If initializer is `None` (the default), the default initializer passed in the variable scope will be used. If that one is `None` too, a `glorot_uniform_initializer` will be used.

The [`glorot_uniform_initializer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6bfbcf31dce9a59acfcad51d905894b082989012/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L527) function initializes values from a uniform distribution.

This function is [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer) as:

> The Glorot uniform initializer, also called Xavier uniform initializer.
>
> It draws samples from a uniform distribution within [-limit, limit],
>   where `limit` is `sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))`
>   where `fan_in` is the number of input units in the weight tensor
>   and `fan_out` is the number of output units in the weight tensor.
>
> Reference: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

Comment: Correction: `glorot_uniform_initializer` is used only for floating types. [Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L828)