# tensorflow: Initializer for variable in LSTM cell

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an RNN to predict the sentiment of input data as positive or negative.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, 40])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, 40])

data = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, 40, 50]), dtype=tf.float32)
data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(glove_embeddings_arr, input_data)

lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_units)
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell = lstm_cell, output_keep_prob = 0.75)
value,state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)

weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([lstm_units, classes]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [classes]))
value = tf.transpose(value, [1,0,2])
last = tf.gather(value, int(value.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
prediction = (tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)



true_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(labels,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(true_pred,tf.float32))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=labels))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

The interpreter returns

```
ValueError: An initializer for variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel of <dtype: 'string'> is required
```

Can someone explain to me this error?

Comment: This is not the whole code right? Have you run something like `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`?

Comment: Yes I've run it during training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are (most probably) feeding raw input text to the network. This is not in your code snippet, but the error indicates **`<dtype: 'string'>`**:

> ValueError: An initializer for variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel of
>   **<dtype: 'string'>** is required

The type is deduced from the input that an LSTM cell gets. Inner LSTM variables (`kernel` and `bias`) are initialized with a default initializer, which (at least now) can deal only with [floating and integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350131/what-is-the-default-variable-initializer-in-tensorflow/37350251), but fails for other types. In your case the type is a `tf.string`, that's why you see this error.

Now, what you should do is transform your input sentences into real vectors. The best way to do this is via [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding), e.g. `word2vec`, but a simple word indexing is also possible. Take a look at [this post](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537), particularly at how they work with text data. There's also a complete working code example.

Comment: Do you by any chance know what default initializer is used? Or how I can find that out?

Comment: Here's the source code - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L826 It's Glorot or zero init