# Tensorflow Convolutional Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I've been trying to implement a convolutional autoencoder in Tensorflow similar to how it was done in Keras in [this tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

So far this is what my code looks like

```
filter1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 16]))
filter2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 8]))
filter3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8]))

d_filter1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8]))
d_filter2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8]))
d_filter3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 16]))
d_filter4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 1]))

def encoder(input_img):
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(input_img, filter1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))# [-1, 28, 28, 16]
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='SAME') # [-1, 14, 14, 16]
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, filter2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) # [-1, 14, 14, 8]
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='SAME') # [-1, 7, 7, 8]
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, filter3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) # [-1, 7, 7, 8]
    pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='SAME') # [-1, 4, 4, 8]

    return pool3

def decoder(encoded):
    d_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(encoded, d_filter1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) # [-1, 4, 4, 8]
    d_pool1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d_conv1) # [-1, 8, 8, 8]
    d_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(d_pool1, d_filter2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) # [-1, 8, 8, 8]
    d_pool2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d_conv2) # [-1, 16, 16, 8]
    d_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(d_pool2, d_filter3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')) # [-1, 14, 14, 16]
    d_pool3 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d_conv3) # [28, 28, 16]
    decoded = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.nn.conv2d(d_pool3, d_filter4, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) # [-1, 28, 28, 1]

    return decoded

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
encoded = encoder(x)
decoded = decoder(mid)
autoencoder = decoder(encoded)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true=x, y_pred=autoencoder))
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)
batch_size = 128
epochs = 50

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_batches = int(x_train.shape[0]/batch_size)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_epoch_loss = 0.0
        for k in range(num_batches):
            batch_x = x_train[k*batch_size:k*batch_size+batch_size]
            feed_dict = {x: batch_x.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])}
            _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            avg_epoch_loss += l

            if k % 100 == 0:
                print 'Step {}/{} of epoch {}/{} completed with loss {}'.format(k, num_batches, epoch, epochs, l)

        avg_epoch_loss /= num_batches
        print 'Epoch {}/{} completed with average loss {}'.format(epoch, epochs, avg_epoch_loss)
        saver.save(sess=sess, save_path='./model.ckpt')

        img = sess.run(autoencoder, feed_dict={x: x_test[0].reshape([1, 28, 28, 1])}).reshape(28, 28)
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

When I train this the loss value tends to go down but then stays around the same (high) value. However, when I replace the `encoder` and `decoder` functions with this, which uses the Keras methods from the above link, the loss decreases at a reasonable rate and converges to a low value.

```
def encoder(input_img):
    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    return encoded

def decoder(encoded):
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

    return decoded
```

I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between these two methods, I've looked over it several times and it seems like my method should be doing the exact same thing as the Keras method. Any help in figuring out what's going on would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The one simple obvious problem in your code is you are not initializing your filters correctly. Try the following, it might work. You can also try some other sophisticated initialization scheme such as [Xavier Inititalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640581/how-to-do-xavier-initialization-on-tensorflow/36784797)

```
filter1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 16], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
filter2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 8], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
filter3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8], mean=0.0, std=0.01))

d_filter1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
d_filter2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 8], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
d_filter3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 16], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
d_filter4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 1], mean=0.0, std=0.01))
```

Answer (score 0):

A difference between your version and the Keras code you point at is the learning rate to the optimizer. Different learning rates can lead to quite different outcomes (convergence, divergence, instabilities).

The tutorial uses a [default learning rate](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adadelta) valued at 1.0. Your version uses the same optimizer (AdaDelta), but you set the learning rate at 0.1.

What if you set the same value? (It may be useful to check that rho, epsilon, and the decay have the same values too).

Comment: Thanks! The solution ended up being a combination of yours and @AbhishekMishra's answer. I needed to use the Xavier Initializer and change the learning rate. I set the value for the learning rate to be 0.1 because I thought that was the default value after looking at the documentation, but I must have looked at AdaGrad. I also changed rho to the default value that the Keras implementation was using.

Comment: How about posting your solution as an answer, and accepting it? Doing so future readers will have a definitive answer.