# How to use He initialization in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

He / MSRA initialization, from *[Delving Deep into Rectifiers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852)*, seems to be a [recommended](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init) weight initialization when using ReLUs.

Is there a built-in way to use this in TensorFlow? (similar to: [How to do Xavier initialization on TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640581/how-to-do-xavier-initialization-on-tensorflow))?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TensorFlow 2.0

[`tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/HeUniform)

or

[`tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/HeNormal)

See docs for usage. (h/t to @mable)

## TensorFlow 1.0

```
tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(dtype=tf.float32)
```

This will give you He / MRSA initialization.  The documentation states that the default arguments for [`tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/variance_scaling_initializer) correspond to He initialization and that changing the arguments can yield Xavier initialization (this is what is done in TF's internal implementation for Xavier initialization).

Example usage:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', shape=[784, 256],
       initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())
```

or

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
W1 = tf.Variable(initializer([784,256]))
```

Comment: For all who stumble across this: By now, the activation is available in `tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal` (or `tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling` using default parameters)

Comment: Could you please explain what is the difference between the  `tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform()` and `tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()`?

Comment: HeUniform draws the weights from a Uniform distribution: U(-x, x). HeNormal draws them from a Normal distribution N(0, x), or something like that, where x is a small value determined by He or Xavier of what not. The documentation should explain it.